# File not found issue in "rdrop2" (shiny)

Tags: shiny, dropbox

I want to delete a file from my Dropbox folder in a Shiny app using "rdrop2". But unfortunately I get an error, which I don't see why.

My code is:

```
library(rdrop2)
print(drop_exists("Edata"))
x <- drop_dir("Edata")
print(x)
drop_delete("Edata/sil.txt")
```

The output I observe is given below

[1] FALSE

**# A tibble: 6 x 11
  .tag   name  path_lower path_display id    client_modified server_modified rev    size is_downloadable content_hash
                                                       
1 folder dene~ /edata/de~ /edata/dene~ id:Y~ NA              NA              NA       NA NA              NA
2 file   DB1.~ /edata/db~ /edata/DB1.~ id:Y~ 2019-06-15T21:~ 2019-06-15T21:~ 11b6~   314 TRUE            16fbbd0ba84~
3 file   DB 2~ /edata/db~ /edata/DB 2~ id:Y~ 2019-06-15T21:~ 2019-06-15T21:~ 11b6~   202 TRUE            3f6029c71b8~
4 file   DB 0~ /edata/db~ /edata/DB 0~ id:Y~ 2019-06-15T21:~ 2019-06-15T21:~ 11b6~   337 TRUE            56bd60dc921~
5 file   DB_0~ /edata/db~ /edata/DB_0~ id:Y~ 2019-06-15T21:~ 2019-06-15T21:~ 11b6~   380 TRUE            036b125a739~
6 file   sil.~ /edata/si~ /edata/sil.~ id:Y~ 2019-06-20T22:~ 2019-06-20T22:~ 11b8~    11 TRUE            a0848be3e4f~*

**Warning: Error in drop_delete: File not found on current path**

I am puzzled because

- drop_exists("Edata") returns FALSE, which means that the folder
  "Edata" does not exist at the root of the Dropbox account,
- however, drop_dir("Edata") lists the folder and its content correctly,
- and when I try to delete an existing file ("sil.txt") using drop_delete("Edata/sil.txt") an error is thrown.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured out the reason after experimenting for hours. It is a case sensitivity issue in "rdrop2". The folder name appears to be "Edata" in Windows but if I change "Edata" to "edata" then drop_delete() functions as expected. It seems like a bug in "rdrop2".